# Hide preliminary computations of tikz path macro, return last line only

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, pgfmath

I want to use a macro `\foo` that defines a path depending on the macro parameters and finally use it inside tikzpictures as follows:

```
\draw[thick] \foo{5}{6};
```

If I have something like

```
\providecommand{\foo}[2]{%
(.5,0) +(0,0) -- (1,#1) +(0,0) -- (-1,#1)
}
```

it works as expected, but as soon as I add some preliminary pgfmath computations like

```
\providecommand{\foo}[2]{%
\pgfmathadd{#1}{#2}% How to hide this?
(.5,0) +(0,0) -- (1,#1) +(0,0) -- (-1,\pgfmathresult)
}
```

I receive the error "Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?".

I am used from METAPOST/METAFONT to write some preliminary computations first and the macro will automatically return the last line only. How can I achieve such a behaviour in TikZ?

(I want `\draw` to be outside of the macro!)

Comment: You can only use macros that (eventually) fully expand to path syntax. Besides that, the result of your addition is lost until you get to your `\pgfmathresult`. Why not simply use `(-1, {#1+#2})` instead? TikZ evaluates this already for you. Anyway. Use `\pgfextra{\pgfmathadd…}` or `[/utils/exec=\pgfmathadd…]` (or define and use your own key that does whatever you need to do with `#1` and `#2`) or use the [`math` library](https://tikz.dev/library-math#pgf./tikz/evaluate) that allows something similar as `[evaluate={\result=#1+#2;}]`. The `calc` library would allow `let \n0={#1+#2} in`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel First, I had trouble with your hints, but `\pgfextra{}` was exactly what I was looking for!